# How can i get current time of background audio? (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, background-audio, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have audio app. For listening audio i use **AVFoundationFramework** and make it in background with info by **MPNowPlayingInfoCenter**. If user making segue to other screen the audio are playing. I want show him info about playing audio on this new screen. The *most problem* is getting *current time* of playing in background audio. **How can i get it?**

P.S.: Length of audio primarily equals to one hour.

P.P.S.: I will be pleased to get answer in any language (obj-c/Swift)

EDIT: in iOS remote center shows true info, i just need get it in code... screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/9lv60eb1n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how make it (take info from remote center), but i solved it by singleton for audio player.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time of the audio via using

[`MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Additional_Metadata_Properties)

e.g. something like

```
if let nowPlayingInfoDict = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo
{
    let elapsedTimeString = nowPlayingInfoDict["MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime"]
}
```

where the value is a NSNumber representing the number of seconds played in the item so far.

Comment: do you get a dictionary (and if so, what are the various keys & values you see in there)?

Comment: i got a dictionary which include all info what i write in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter: title, name etc.. but ElapsedPlaybackTime is NULL

Comment: Oh, is the thing you are playing a local file or some streaming thing from a remote site (in which case there is no fixed duration)?

Comment: online and offline. in both cases i know duration and current time for AVPlayer, but for background audio don't working in both cases

Comment: in iOS remote center shows true info, i just need get it in code... screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/9lv60eb1n/